# Data pivot transformation

Tags: r, text

I am aware of some packages in R for text mining like tm but I am unable to use it for my task.
I have a text file that has data something like this:

```
 452924301037
    5May2014
       John
    7May2014
       Mark
       Sam
 452924302789
    6May2014
       Bill
```

I want the above data in a data frame as something like this:

```
UserID, Date, Names
452924301037,5May2014,John
452924301037,7May2014,Mark Sam
452924302789,6May2014,Bill
```

How can I do this in R?

**Example 2:**

Input textfile:

```
452924301037
    5May2014
       John
           Cricket
           Football
    7May2014
       Mark
           Hockey
452924302789
     6May2014
       Bill
           Billiards
```

And I want to setup a data frame as below:

```
Game, Player, Date, UserID 
Cricket, John, 5May2014, 452924301037
Football, John, 5May2014, 452924301037
Hockey, Mark, 7May2014, 452924301037
Billiards, Bill, 6May2014, 452924302789
```

Comment: where is `52924301037` coming from?

Comment: Updated it. Same as the parent userID

Comment: You need to make it reproducible. Use `dput`

Comment: I've rolled back the edit an subsequently included the 2nd example dataset such that the original is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution using `data.table` and `zoo`:

```
# read the textfile
txt <- readLines('textlines.txt')

# load the needed packages
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

# convert the text to a data.table (an enhanced form of a dataframe)
DT <- data.table(txt = txt)

# extract the info into new columns
DT[grepl('\\d+{8,}', txt), User_id := grep('\\d+{8,}', txt, value = TRUE)
   ][grepl('\\D+{3}\\d+{4}', txt), Date := txt
     ][, (c('User_id','Date')) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), .SDcols = 2:3
       ][txt!=User_id & txt != Date, .(Names = paste0(txt, collapse = ' ')), by = .(User_id, Date)]
```

which gives:

```
        user_id     date    Names
1: 452924301037 5May2014     John
2: 452924301037 7May2014 Mark Sam
3: 452924302789 6May2014     Bill
```

To see what each step does, run the following code:

```
# extract the user_id's
DT[grepl('\\d+{8,}', txt), User_id := grep('\\d+{8,}', txt, value = TRUE)][]
# extract the dates
DT[grepl('\\D+{3}\\d+{4}', txt), Date := txt][]
# fill the NA-values of 'User_id' and 'Date' with na.locf from the zoo package
DT[, (c('User_id','Date')) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), .SDcols = 2:3][]
# filter out the rows where the 'txt'-column has either a 'User_id' or a 'Date'
# collapse the names into one string by 'User_id' and 'Date'
DT[txt != User_id & txt != Date, .(Names = paste0(txt, collapse = ' ')), by = .(User_id, Date)][]
```

---

For the added 2nd example, you could do:

```
DT <- data.table(txt = trimws(txt))

DT[grepl('\\d+{8,}', txt), User_id := grep('\\d+{8,}', txt, value = TRUE)
   ][grepl('\\D+{3}\\d+{4}', txt), Date := txt
     ][, (c('User_id','Date')) := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE), .SDcols = 2:3
       ][txt!=User_id & txt != Date
         ][, Name := txt[1], by = .(User_id, Date)
           ][Name != txt]
```

which gives:

```
         txt      User_id     Date Name
1:   Cricket 452924301037 5May2014 John
2:  Football 452924301037 5May2014 John
3:    Hockey 452924301037 7May2014 Mark
4: Billiards 452924302789 6May2014 Bill
```

Comment: Can you help me with a little variant of the original question ? i have edited the question. I am trying to construct a data frame wherein each children should have a single row in the data frame and it's column entities coming from their respective parent data.

Comment: I tried the approach for the 1st question and on `DT[txt!=User_id & txt != Date, .(Names = paste0(txt, collapse = ' ')), by = .(User_id, Date)][]` I get `Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: User_id,Date,Names` in console. Thanks for the approach to second question. I will try that.

Comment: And could you also let me know any useful links that would help me with these kind of transformations. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @AYa I can't reproduce the error. Did you follow the exact steps I described?

Comment: after spending a lot of hours on this POC, I have figured a weird bug. If in place of 'John', If I manually modify the text file and write ' John@gmail.com.123.eml' then the code works. But the same modification if I copy paste in the text file, the code gives less number of rows (3 in this case).  Problem is I have a huge text file that follows this pattern and I can't be manually writing all the names part. Why would this be happening?